# If test on Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, if-statement, pandas, dataframe

I would like to do an if test on the 'ave_data' DataFrame below:

ave_data=

Time     ------------   F7 ---------------  F8 ---------------  F9
00:00:00    ----   43.005593  ----    -56.509746  ----     25.271271
01:00:00    ----   55.114918  ----    -59.173852   ----    31.849262
02:00:00    ----   63.990762   ----   -64.699492   ----    52.426017

Specifically, I would like to test if any of the values are **less than** 0.05 and output 1 if they are **not**, and 0 if they **are**, so that the output (named, for example, 'tested_ave_data') looks like this:

tested_ave_data=

Time     ------------   F7 --- -------  F8 ----------  F9
00:00:00    --------   1  ------------    0  ------------     1
01:00:00    --------   1  ------------    0   ------------    1
02:00:00    --------   1   ------------   0   ------------    1

Can anyone help me develop a code to do this? I've searched for ways to do this for a long time now but not been successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to "develop" any code if I understand your question correctly. Just use a Boolean mask -- everything is already implemented in pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

a = [[2., .3, 4., 5.], [.8, .03, 0.02, 5.]]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df
```

[image]

```
df <= 0.05
```

[image]

```
df = df < 0.05
df.astype(int)
```

[image]